# Grizzly2 + jax-rs + Injection

Tags: java, jax-rs, grizzly

I'm creating a Embedded server with Grizzly2 and Jersey, and came to me a need of load a configuration from a injection to all Rest connections. Im trying to understand how works injection in general. I tried a test but not worked.

```
public class ConfigBinder extends AbstractBinder{

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(BinderTeste.class).to(restMainService.class);
    }
}


 public class BinderTeste {

    public String bTeste = "BTESTE";

    public BinderTeste(){

    }
}
```

and every time I tried a connection I'm getting this:

```
mai 07, 2015 5:23:53 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder process
GRAVE: Error occurred when processing a response created from an already mapped exception.
```

**EDITED:**

```
public class AppWS extends ResourceConfig {

    public AppWS(String db){
        CFFMasterClass MasterClass = new CFFMasterClass();
        setConfig(MasterClass.getCurrentConfig());
        InicializaLogger();
        try{
            File currentPath = null;
            if(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().contains("jar")){
                currentPath = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
                System.out.println(currentPath.getPath().substring(0,currentPath.getPath().lastIndexOf(File.separator)));
                ExtractWSMethods(new File(currentPath.getPath().substring(0,currentPath.getPath().lastIndexOf(File.separator))));
            }else{
                currentPath = new File("c://CompuService//lib");
                ExtractWSMethods(currentPath);
            }
            register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            GeraLog.error(ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            Iterator<Class<?>> iter = registerclasses.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Class<?> tempClass = iter.next();
                register(tempClass);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            GeraLog.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        register(new ConfigBinder());
        LogManager.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: My server is embedded with my application using grizzly2 server api, so don't have configuration file and I just use ResourceConfig to register my classes. I'm trying get some information about Injection and CDI apis to improve my app. some sugestion from where can I start use injection on embedded server ?

Comment: Actually I just need pass a class object to current rest session.

Comment: Here http://pastebin.com/cWhqrrvg